# How to Detect Optional First Parameter in Lua Callback?

Tags: c++, c, lua

I have a LUA callback in C/++ and I'm trying to use `lua_gettop()` to detect an optional first parameter. The problem is that `lua_gettop(L) == 1` is always true, even when I don't provide any parameters in LUA.

Here's the basics of my callback function in C/++:

```
int LuaFile::l_cpp_my_callback(lua_State *L) {
    LuaFilePtr my_this = lua_map_[L];

    if ( lua_gettop(L) == 0 ) {
        // I never get here
    } else if(lua_gettop(L) == 1) {
        // Always gets here
    } else {
        return 1;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

This is the context of the call in the LUA code:

```
function my_function()
    if ... then
        if not ... then
            if ... then
                someOtherCallback(param, param, param)
                someOtherCallback(param)
            end
            if ... then
                someOtherCallback(param)
            end
        end

    else
        if not ... then
            if ... then
                someOtherCallback(param, param, param)
                someOtherCallback(param)
            end
            if ... then
                someOtherCallback(param)
            end
        end
        var = my_callback()
        ...
    end
end
```

I used `lua_gettype(L, 1)` to debug and it returns '5', which `lua_typename(L, 5)` says is a 'table'. I'm guessing this is a metatable of the stack?

I understand that 0 isn't a valid index in the LUA stack but then what's the proper way to determine optional first parameters?

Comment: Is the call from lua 'object based' i.e. `instance:method()`, if so then the first argument is always `instance` which is usually a table.

Comment: @nate No, I don't believe the call is object based, I'm simply calling the method such as `my_callback()`, as opposed to providing an instance `instance:my_callback()`

Comment: i believe if you have function which can have 1 argument, for each call lua will put on stack provided argument or nil

Comment: @AndrewKashpur I used the `lua_isnoneornil(L, 1)` and it returned 0... In fact, I used all of the lua_is... functions and the only positive return was from `lua_istable()`

Comment: can you post more of the context of your lua code that calls the callback?  Assuming it's not an instance method, the first ('1') stack value should be your parameter.  So if it's not, something else is getting pushed onto the stack

Comment: @avariant I've updated my question with more LUA code context; I figured what was happening after wasn't important... All I'm doing is a few other callbacks before the callback in question and I wouldn't think they'd have any impact on that stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @nate mentioned in his comment, any "object-based" function call, that is, calling a member function--or method, if you prefer--results in the object being the first thing on the Lua stack. `lua_gettop` would return `1`, assuming nothing else was passed to the member function as an argument.

As for checking an optional first argument to the member function, which would be located at index `2` on the Lua stack if you were using an object-based call, functions like `luaL_optstring` are very helpful. (Reference page [here](https://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/luaL_optstring). In case you are unaware, functions prefixed with `luaL` are located in `lauxlib.h`.) There are also equivalent functions for other types. It allows one to provide an index and a default argument: if a value exists at the given index on the Lua stack, it is returned; otherwise, the default value supplied to the function is returned.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I don't think I'm making an object-based function call... or am I (see LUA code in question)? When I provide a parameter to the callback in LUA, `lua_gettop(L, 1) == 1` is still `true` and my paramter is at `1`. Your response says my parameter would be at index `2` if I were using an object-based call & that's not the case.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the type `lua_map_`, but you are indexing it like you would an array with `operator[]`. Perhaps that is why you appear to have a table on the top of the stack. Also, regardless of what is at index `1`, would your optional argument not still be at index `2`?

Comment: The `lua_map_` line is irrelevant in the scenario... nonetheless, after further testing, it seems that you're right because my optional parameter is at `2`